# How to find out what is breaking Apache2 in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2

I had Apache2 with MySQL and PHP working perfectly fine in Ubuntu. I ran the command 
"sudo pecl install pdo_dobc", 
restarted Apache and now wont display any pages on the server as if it didn't restart properly.

When I restarted I had a message saying "httpd (no pid file) not running."

Any help will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/var/log/apache2/error.log` will probably tell you exactly what's gone wrong.

Comment: It certainly put my on a path to finding the problem. I found that if I deleted the contents of the error.log file restarted apache, i mananaged to pinpoint the error in the log which was "/usr/sbin/apache2: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: php_pdo_get_dbh_ce" after searching for a while on google, I by chance was able to restore /usr/lib/php5/20060613+lfs/pdo.so from a backup which apparently loads before pdo_mysql.so, I think there was some compatability problems or something when I tried to install pdo_odbc.